# Hdd speed goes lower. 2 Internal HDD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, sata, speed

hey i was using 320gb hdd today i install 1tb another hdd.
after that 1tb hdd get 180mb/s but 320gb gets 99mb ? why? and isnt both should get 180mb/s?
using both sata2 cable

> /dev/sdb:  Timing cached reads:   7556 MB in  2.00 seconds = 3778.75
>   MB/sec  Timing buffered disk reads: 544 MB in  3.00 seconds = 181.08
>   MB/sec :~$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda
>
> /dev/sda:  Timing cached reads:   7582 MB in  2.00 seconds = 3791.37
>   MB/sec  Timing buffered disk reads: 300 MB in  3.01 seconds =  99.69
>   MB/sec :~$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda

Comment: What did the 320GB read before you added the 1TB? Or is that not your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All else being equal (such as RPM and interface), larger capacity drives usually have higher throughput for one simple reason- more bits pass under the read/write head for each revolution.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areal_density_(computer_storage)#Effects_on_performance)